# django: handler for inline admin save

Tags: python, django, django-admin

When a user clicks the 'save' button on a model page of my django site, I want to do something with all the models that are to be updated, all at once. If I override `save_model`, it is called once per each object, but I want one function to be called with all objects to-be-updated. I overrode `save_formset` but it didn't work:

```
class ShadingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('foo', 'bar', 'baz')
    list_editable = ('bar', 'baz')
    list_display_links = ('foo',)
    def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):
        print "FOO"

admin.site.register(Shading, ShadingAdmin)
```

`"FOO"` is never printed.

I'm using Django 1.2.

Comment: ...but, at the end of the day isn't the same? you'll still have separate insert/update calls for each model afaik.

Comment: @equinoxel: Not if you coded some custom SQL... which I want to trigger... which I need all the instances at once for.

Comment: can you override .save() in the formset?

Comment: @equinoxel: What's the formset? All I have is this subclass of `admin.ModelAdmin`. I'm not too well-versed in the Django ways. I do have total control of the code, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: oops. my bad. I assume your code is something like "if formset is valid: formset.save()"? Or are you using the formset in the admin interface?

Comment: No, my code is like: `admin.site.register(Shading, ShadingAdmin)`. Not entirely sure what a `formset` is but I don't have a handle to one sa it is now.

Comment: to make this clearer I updated the example. foo, bar, baz are all displayed - bar + baz are editable. the admin page lists 20 `Shading` objects. I modify the bar of 5 and the baz of 10 others. When `Save` is clicked, I want a function to be called, in which I can get those 15 instances.

Answer (score 1):

formset.save() [returns a list of all objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset) from the formset. You can call it with **commit=False** and the changes are only validated, not saved in the DB.

save_formset() is only called by admin (you can do a grep in django's source).

Comment: Why isn't `save_formset()` of the `ModelAdmin` being called when I click `save` on the admin page, then? (Not on `save` for the specific object, but on the `save` for the inline objects)

Comment: I'm a bit confused.. Are you using the admin interface?

Comment: yes. the entirety of my admin code (in `admin.py`) is in the question. That `save_formset` function is never called. Note that I am editing the objects inline - editing the fields in the `list_editable` tuple.

Comment: I've looked into the code and the save_formset is called on add_view() and on change_view(). But, as the doc says, it's called only if all elements are valid (check e.g. django/contrib/admin/options.py line around 798). From what I see, there's no exception thrown if the all_valid() fails. Try to run it in debug mode and put breakpoint before the all_valid() call. I have a sneaking suspicion that at least one of your objects fails..